# Yield return and Parallel ForEach

Tags: c#

Below is the test sample of the code
[...]

```
    public IEnumerable<B> GetList(A obj)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(obj.yTest.Keys, key =>
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "1":
                    yield return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                    break;
                case "2":
                    yield return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                    break;
                case "3":
                    yield return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                    break;
                case "4":
                    yield return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Error:
"Only methods, operators and accessors could contain 'yield' statement"

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28VS.80%29.aspx and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407162/what-is-yield-return-in-c

Comment: what are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `yield` inside a lambda like that. However what you could do is replace your `Parallel.ForEach` with a [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) select statement.

```
public IEnumerable<B> GetList(A obj)
{
    return obj.yTest.Keys.AsParallel().Select(key =>
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case "1":
                return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                break;
            case "2":
                return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                break;
            case "3":
                return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                break;
            case "4":
                return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                break;
            default:
                return new B() {Name = obj.yTest[key]};
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

and that will give you parallel selection in to a `IEnumerable` along with the deferred execution you would have gotten from `yield return`.